# Bluetooth audio device lags after a minute of playback

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-11, bluetooth

When I play any media on any earbuds using my HP Pavilion laptop, it starts out perfectly fine, but after a minute or so, there is a one second audio loss and then it starts to lag.
I've tried

- Updating Windows
- Updating Bluetooth Driver
- Reinstalling bluetooth drivers
- Disabling Audio Enhancements
- Drivers from HP Official Website

I tried everything in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1588631/why-is-there-audio-lag-with-bluetooth-earbuds-in-windows-10).
Interestingly, it syncs after I pause and wait for a few seconds, but the problem occurs again after a minute as I said

Audio Device - Realtek Wireless Bluetooth Adapter
Windows 11 23H2